# Getting values within intersect layers and autofilling attributes to another layer form when creating new object

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers, intersect

When I am creating a point that intersects on a polygon, how can I get values from the attribute polygon and autofill the attribute in the point layer?

I am using QGIS 3.12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your point layer, open the "Field Calculator", choose to update the field you want and run the following expression by changing it with your own layer and field names:

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'yourpolygonlayerid',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=attribute('ATTRIBUTENAMEFROMTHEPOLYGONYOUWANT'),
concatenator:=',',
filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry)
)
```

You can reuse the same expression to "Create a virtual field" if you want. In this case, you will not need to run the expression each time you add a new point to your point layer to get your field updated.

There are several constraints you should know to be sure it works. Here, I suppose:

- your polygons do not overlap
- there are no case where one of your points is touching exactly two polygons (or you will get more than one value in the field)
- your two layers (points and polygons) use the same projections (or `intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry)` will not work and you will need to reproject)

Beware that you should avoid using this type of expression when you have millions of points or polygons for performances reasons.

*Edit to highlight the comment feedback*

From @Alexandre-Neto comment, you can also use this same expression on the field default (layer properties > forms)

Answer (score 1):

Using overlay_intersects can be more efficient because of the use of LIMIT.

```
attribute(
  get_feature_by_id(
    'polygon_layer_name',
    map_get(overlay_intersects(
     layer:='polygon_layer_name',
     expression:= $geometry, return_details:=true, limit:=1)[0], 'id')
    ),
'ATTRIBUTE_YOU_WANT')
```